# Table on Webpage not visible in view page source and inspect option not available on right click it. How to automate clicking using selenium + python

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, selenium, dom

I am trying to automated the process of logging in to a website, and downloading data using Selenium + Python. The data is visible on webpage in a table format, each row represents a folder, we need to click the row and then the files in the folder appear.

I am using Selenium + Python.

The issue is to select a specific row in table, I need either xpath, id, link text etc, but when i  do page source, table is not visible, when I right click the table I do not get "Inspect" element option.

The table is dynamically created ( as in the rows will change if any user created a new folder). Also when I manually click a row of table, it creates a new table with files (in the folder) as rows, but the url of the webpage does not change.

How do i find a specific identifier for my code to 1st select the right row and then click it.

Comment: *"I am trying to automated the process of logging in to a website..."* is all i need to know that i ethically will not help you. Beyond that you show **zero** source code attempt so your question is not debugabble.

Comment: @mardubbles I agree with your comment, Sorry i am running this program on an internal company webpage. Hence could not share more information. I think there is enough information provided here for someone to at least prod me in right direction.

Comment: You have to use a customized Xpath with explicit wait. You have to check the pattern of dynamically appeared xpath and will have to create an xpath according to that after that will have to target that xpath using explicit wait. However, It's not possible to debug the exact issue without seeing the code/web URL on which you're doing this stuff.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can hit F12 to see the inspect panel. If it's the only table just use `//table`